# How to use altair.Data

Tags: altair

How to use `altair.Data`?

This data structure is very opaque to me. I checked the doc, https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Data.html, but still not sure what it exactly refers to.

Comment: You rarely (never?) need to use `altair.Data` directly. Most of the time you pass your data as a dataframe using pandas, polars, etc; or as a URL. Is there a specific use case you want to achieve that is not supported in other ways?